# How to use a lookup table in Jinja?

Tags: python, jinja2, lookup-tables

In my Jinja template I have a list of tuples like this one:

```
{% set typeLabels = [
    ('type1', 'Label for type 1'),
    ('type2', 'Label for type 2'),
    ('type3', 'Label for type 3')
] %}
```

I use a `list` and not a `dict` because the order is important (I also use the list elsewhere to generate a listbox).

Then I need to do lookups like this one:

```
{{ dict(typeLabels)[someType] }}
```

which works fine if you do it inside Python, but in Jinja it doesn't work.

How can I do this in Jinja?

Comment: `OrderedDict` from `collections` if order is important.

Comment: Yes, but what is the notation for an ordered dict?

Comment: You can also create a customer filter. http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#writing-filters

Comment: @GetFree: Just pass your list of tuples into `OrderedDict()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since there's no answers I'll post my solution based on the suggestions.

First you have to add `collections.OrderedDict` to the Jinja environment since Jinja doesn't know about it:

```
JINJA_ENV = jinja2.Environment( . . . )
JINJA_ENV.globals['OrderedDict'] = collections.OrderedDict
```

And then in the template:

```
{% set typeLabels = OrderedDict([
    ('type1', 'Label for type 1'),
    ('type2', 'Label for type 2'),
    ('type3', 'Label for type 3')
]) %}
```

So now you can access the dictionary normally:

```
{{ typeLabels[someType] }}
```

Comment: As an update, as of python 3.7, native `dict`s officially preserve order.